# How To Add a Variable Height to React Styled Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to add a variable height to only one object in Data.js. I want the other objects to stay at default height.

Data.js

```
export const homeObjFive = {
    id: 'text',
    lightBg: false,
    lightText: true,
    lightTextDesc: true,
    topLine: 'text',
    headlineFontSize:'30px',
    headline:'#',
    description:'#',
    buttonLabel: 'text',
    imgStart: false,
    img: Doc,
   ** imgHeight: false,**
    alt: 'Map',
    dark: true,
    link:'#',
    primary: true,
    darkText: false,
   /*  customFontSize: '40px' */
};

export const homeObjSix = {
    id: 'text',
    lightBg: true,
    lightText: false,
    lightTextDesc: false,
    topLine: 'text',
    headline:'text',
    description:'text',
    buttonLabel: 'text',
    imgStart: true,
    **imgHeight: true,**
    img: Tree,
    alt: 'Map',
    dark: true,
    primary: true,
    link:'contact',
    darkText: true
};
```

InfoElements.js

```
    export const Img = styled.img`
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding-right:0;
 ** height: ${imgHeight => imgHeight === true ? "300px" : null}**
```

I tried to create a variable height by creating an imgHeight attribute for the objects. I attempted to create logic in InfoElements.js that would give a specific height if imgHeight is true and default height if false. Not sure where I went wrong.